# Ember server only resolves files with the bower path used in the brocfile

Tags: bower, ember-cli, node-modules

In my ember cli app I have moment in both directories, but my ember server only works with the bower path, in my borcfile:

`app.import("bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js");`

`app.import("node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js");`

the latter says that it can't find it.

Comment: Node modules are imported by their name, no need to set the path.

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero thanks, put it in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reference node modules you ll need to import them by their name, the simplest example is: `import Ember from 'ember'`.

For more info regarding modules and the resolver refer to [this](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules) part of the documentation